Is there any way to bypass macOS Sonoma’s restriction of modifying OS files?
I wanted to modify the macOS startup icon that appears at boot, and I managed to find the exact location (at least I think)
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LoginUIKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LoginUICore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/apple.png

But obviously I couldn’t edit it. So I tried sudo, disabling SIP, login as root and mount -uw / (this one just threw an error message), and even so when I tried to unlock the file it said that it’s on a read only volume. After some digging I found out that it’s a “safety feature” that cuts access off from core files. Maybe there’s some way out there to make that volume editable or something like that.. but right now I’m stuck.

Can that file be modified? Certainly, unless it actually had resided on the board in silicon(literally, written in stone).
To modify or replace it, boot from other media, so that the main drive is not mounted. Look at Bootcamp for directions.
Should you? There are reasons not to do so.

The OS might have a checksum for that file, and any substitute for it could prevent the PC from booting.
Why would that restriction be in place? Aside from the manufacturer wanting to preserve look, feel, and display its corporate logo, changing the logo file opens up a path for malicious attack, LogoFAIL. However, "Intel Apple Macs, which used UEFI to boot, can't be attacked by LogoFAIL. That protection happens because Apple has hardcoded its logo image files into the UEFI."

A change to certain files can make a machine unusable.

Changes in fundamental files might violate any warranty.


If you do decide to personalize your machine, first make a full disk image, verify it, and test that it can be restored before making any change.
